# Веб-Камера на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-служба

Здравствуйте!
В данный момент Я разрабатываю сервис, с помощью которого люди будут записывать 
видео со своей вебки прямо на сайте. Но я столкнулся с тем, что не знаю, как 
сделать запись видео прямо на сайте. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как эту проблему
можно решить. Спасибо.

Comment: нече себе задача =) думаю тут надо юзать флеш или сильверЛайт....

Comment: да? ох..тяжело, тяжело... может стоит поискать готовые решения?

Answer (score 4):

> может стоит поискать готовые решения?

[Стоит](http://blogs.adobe.com/mikepotter/2006/06/record_video_fr.html), конечно, [стоит](http://www.experiments.flashmatics.co.uk/ccount/click.php?id=34).

Comment: Ну... Вроде как да. =) Там даже описание есть...